# Don't open fancybox on click of a particular dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

> I have a condition of where i have a drop-down with 5 options on it.
>   on-click of any option, the "fancybox" modal window opens. But i don't
>   want to open the fancybox when click on "option 1". according to the
>   conditions, I can't place "Value attribute for Option 1". Other all
>   have value attribute.

```
    function openFB(focusAeraData, idData) {
    var userIdData = $("#userIdData").val();
    var focusAreaSelectBoxValue01 = $("#focusAera1").val();
    var focusAreaSelectBoxValue02 = $("#focusAeraFirst").val();
    var focusAreaSelectBoxValue03 = $("#focusAeraSecond").val();

    if ((focusAreaSelectBoxValue01 == focusAreaSelectBoxValue02 || focusAreaSelectBoxValue02 == focusAreaSelectBoxValue03)
            && idData == 2) {
        $("#focusAeraError2").html('Please Select different Focus');
        $("#focusAeraFirst").val('');
        $("#focusAreaContent2").html('');
        $('#foucusAreaLaunchURL2').html("");
        $('#focusAeraFirst>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#focusAeraError3").html('');
        $("#focusAeraError1").html('');
    } else if ((focusAreaSelectBoxValue01 == focusAreaSelectBoxValue03 || focusAreaSelectBoxValue02 == focusAreaSelectBoxValue03)
            && idData == 3) {
        $("#focusAeraError3").html('Please Select different Focus');
        $("#focusAeraSecond").val('');
        $('#focusAeraSecond>option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        $("#focusAeraError2").html('');
        $('#foucusAreaLaunchURL3').html("");
        $("#focusAreaContent3").html('');
        $("#focusAeraError1").html('');
    }

    else {

        $("#focusAeraError" + idData).html('');
        getValueDataRemove(idData);
        var OpenPOPUPURL = '../../pop_up/get_popup_scorecard?idData='
                + idData + '&focusAeraData=' + focusAeraData + '&userId='
                + userIdData;
        $.fancybox({
            autoSize : true,
            'maxWidth' : '35%',
            'minWidth' : '35%',
            'width' : '680',
            modal           : false,
            fitToView : true,
            'padding-bottom' : '5px',
            arrows : false,
            openEffect : 'fade',
            openSpeed : 'slow',
            closeEffect : 'fade',
            closeSpeed : 'slow',
            closeBtn : false, 
            href : OpenPOPUPURL, //Your form must have an action.
            type : 'ajax',
            'helpers' : { 
                'overlay' : {
                    'closeClick': false,
                }
            },
            ajax : {
                type : "GET",
                cache : false,
                data : $(this).serializeArray(),
            },
            scrolling : 'no',

            iframe : {
                scrolling : 'auto',
                preload : true
            }

        })

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the generated html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `can't place "Value attribute for Option 1"`, then just check if there is value and skip if there is not. For example:

```
if ( !focusAreaSelectBoxValue01 || !focusAreaSelectBoxValue02 || !focusAreaSelectBoxValue03 ) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: i Have tried this by placing it in if condition above but then my fancybox was not opening at all.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to condition the fancybox to open except when you change to option1, then you can do something like this

made a simple example because your html is not posted. but you get the idea. You just have to insert the fancybox inside the if condition

see snippet below

```js
$("select").on("change", function() {
  if (!this.selectedIndex == 0) {
    $(this).css({
      'color': 'red'
    })
  } else {
    $(this).css({
      'color': 'black'
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<select>
<option>Option1</option>
<option>Option2</option>
<option>Option3</option>
<option>Option4</option>
<option>Option5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Agreed with your function but the whole problem is that it's not a color. it's a fancybox and code have done by other guys that on select fancybox opens ..

Comment: well. i made you only an example. instead of ` $(this).css({ .... ` you can disable/enable the fancybox inside that IF condition